# Flutter back button is hidden on navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

Why `MaterialApp` hides back button from `AppBar` for my new screen. I have many screens in my app, where I need to use `ThemeData`. To do that,  I use `MaterialApp` in another screen, but I don't see any `back` arrow on the `AppBar()`.

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'IranSansLight',
    textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'IranSansLight'),
        title: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'IranSansLight'),
        body1: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(fontFamily: 'IranSansLight', color: Colors.black)),
  ),
  home: ScopedModel(
    model: CounterModel(),
    child: Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading:true,title: Text('aaaa'),),
          body: Container(
          )),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `MaterialApp` for all individual screen, there should be only one `MaterialApp` widget throughout the app.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad now, how can i have `ThemeData`, i had to have that in individual screen to force change some theme options

Comment: Yes, you can have, all you need to do is use `Theme.of(context),copyWith(...)`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad i tested that before asking question, for `Html` library, i had to change theme options

Comment: I'm not sure what `HTML` library is, but the logic should be same for any library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `MaterialApp` for all individual screens, this is not the correct way, all you need is just one `MaterialApp` for the entire app.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: HomePage()), // MaterialApp widget should be used only here
  );
}
```

And whenever you need to use `Theme` in your 2nd screen, use something like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      // override whatever you need like
      textTheme: TextTheme(...),
    ),
    child: Scaffold(),
  );
}
```

Comment: could you show me how can i override `textTheme` please?